# Javascript scope access in self-executing method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I'm quite confused with a problem when defining a Module pattern (http://robots.thoughtbot.com/module-pattern-in-javascript-and-coffeescript):

The following piece of code works as exepted (CoffeeScript):

```
window.Map = {}

Map.handle = ( ->
  handle = 'some text'

  print: () ->
    console.log handle    
)()
```

now if I replace `'some text'` by a method from a library available in the global scope (namely gmaps4rails: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails):

```
window.Map = {}

Map.handle = ( ->
  handle = Gmaps.build('Google')

  print: () ->
    console.log handle    
)()
```

the code does not work and throws `Map.handle` is undefined. So I thought that it's a problem of scope so I tried passing `Gmaps.build('Google')` as a parameter to the anonymous function but it failed.

Gmaps.build works properly itself since doing:

```
window.Map = {}

Map.handle = ( ->

  mapBuildFx = () ->
    handle = Gmaps.build('Google')
)()
```

works as expected.

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no reason to throw `Map.handle is undefined` from the given code. How do you use you "singleton" object?

Answer (score 1):

When I try any version of your code, I obtain `ReferenceError: Map is not defined`.

I don't know if this is really your issue, but at very least, you forgot to qualify `Map` as `window.Map`:

```
window.Map = {}

window.Map.handle = ( ->
  handle = Gmaps.build('Google')

  print: () ->
    console.log handle    
)()

# Use `print` like that:
do window.Map.handle.print
# or
window.Map.handle.print()
```

<sub>Not tested with Gmaps</sub>

---

Letting aside some other minor error and/or Gmap peculiarities (?), and to answer to the question as titled: **Javascript scope access in self-executing method**:

In that fragment, `handle` is local to the anonymous function. So it is visible anywhere inside of its definition -- even in sub-functions. But unless you let it escape somehow, it will be hidden from the outside:

```
coffee> console.log window.Map.handle
{ print: [Function] }
```

BTW, you might have use `do ->` in the function definition instead of the less idiomatic `( -> ...)()`.

Comment: Yes of yourse, I simply didn't paste the line here, let me update that :)